# Drupal 7 Domain Access Module Gives 500 error, WSOD for subdomains

Tags: 7, domain-access

I am attempting to get Drupal 7's domain access module working.
I have the original domain that the site was built on, and 2 more domains,
all configured from a local apache virtual host configuration.

I can log in and configure with the original domain name "localhost",
but when I try to log in with any of the other domains I configured I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Domains Configured (for local use):
1)localhost
2)drupalx.domainaccess.com
3)drupaly.domainaccess.com

This is the domain configuration page for domain's in Drupal.  Note I have 3 domains configured, localhost, drupalx, drupaly.
[image]

I know that the domains I set up work because if they did not then this next image would have a warning saying that the domain module could not access files on the domain name.
I also verified this by using the drupalx/drupaly domains and I was able to access css files in a subfolder of the drupal install using these domains.

[image]

Here is the home page for the drupalx domain. The only page that can be accesssed is the home page.

[image]

If I try to go to any other page in drupalx or drupaly I get a 500 error, WSOD.

[image]

Here is my virtual host setup

[image]

I don't have any drupal reports on this, and my apache logs only gave the 500 error info

ie:
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Apr/2014:16:54:46 -0700] "GET /user/register HTTP/1.1" 500 530

Comment: Define your subdomains as ServerAlias not separate vhosts as they all have the same doc root.

Comment: Probably @DavidThomas is right, **but** we can't be sure it is the only reason unless you will post your server's actual logs. `HTTP 500` basically means "you, as a client, shouldn't care what's wrong, and server admin should look into error log". The message displayed to you told you just that! So please do, and paste all relevant parts of the log file.

Comment: Also note that random guesses are *not* welcome here - we aim to create a high quality knowledge base. Usable by community, not only by you.

Comment: Another note, recommended to remove the partial rewrite rules from the vhost scope. You could add the full content from Drupal .htaccess. It should also be under the Directory stanza.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, might as well add a tentative answer on this one.

Add your subdomains using ServerAlias within the same single VirtualHost, because they all have the same document root.

```
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias drupalx.example.com
ServerAlias drupaly.example.com
```

Fix the stray rewrite stanza in virtualhost scope.

e.g put it inside the Directory block.

```
<Directory "C:\xammp\www">
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
  </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

However, the latter isn't really needed if using the default .htaccess file in your doc root. Alternatively, remove .htaccess and copy its contents to the Directory block instead.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you very much for your help. You are my hero.