# Using Domain Access produces HTTP code 500

Tags: 7, .htaccess, domain-access

I was having a 500 error when going to subdomain. I looked at this thread, [Drupal 7 Domain Access Module Gives 500 error, WSOD for subdomains](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111199/drupal-7-domain-access-module-gives-500-error-wsod-for-subdomains), and managed to get rid of the 500 errors by editing my htaccess file. However, I now get a Page not found on homepages.

In my htaccess, if I use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The last line is giving me Error 500 when I start switching between main domain and sub-domains

However, if I use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

the last line gets me rid of the Error 500. But when I go to the domain or sub-domain homepage and refresh it, I get a Page not found

So what is the right line to put in my htaccess to prevent both errors?

Thanks.